# Implementing SimpleSelect with "Read More" option in Dropdown List

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a web project and need to implement a dropdown list using SimpleSelect. I want to include a "Read More" option in the dropdown list for items that have more than 10 records while i search with characters.

Current Implementation have

```
<SimpleSelect
    ref={this.addressSelect}
    options={this.state.addressSelectorList}
    search={this.state.searchString}
    onSearchChange={this.searchAddress}
    placeholder={i18n.t('search_for_address')}
    theme='bootstrap3'
    onValueChange={this.setAddress}
    value={this.state.addressValue}
    onBlur={this.addressBlur}
    renderOption={this.renderOption}
    renderValue={this.renderValue}
    filterOptions={this.filterAddress}
    restoreOnBackspace={item => {
    return item.label.substr(0, item.label.length - 1);
/>
```

on UI looks like

[image]

After 5 Records have to show show more button to show 5 more and keep on increment till it reaches all results